# SilverStripe control ChildrenOf with multi language

Tags: internationalization, silverstripe

I have a Problem with the ChildrenOf(pagename) and multilanguage.

When i use

```
<% control ChildrenOf(aktuelles/messen).Limit(2) %>
```

It works in German but not English.

So i added

```
public function PageByLang($url, $lang) {
    $SQL_url = Convert::raw2sql($url);
    $SQL_lang = Convert::raw2sql($lang);

    $page = Translatable::get_one_by_lang('SiteTree', $SQL_lang, "URLSegment = '$SQL_url'");
if ($page->Locale != Translatable::get_current_locale()) {
    $page = $page->getTranslation(Translatable::get_current_locale());
}
return $page;
}
```

to my Page Controller and in the Template:

```
<% control ChildrenOf(PageByLang(aktuelles/messen, de_DE)).Limit(2) %>
```

But its still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if its a good approach but i solved my problem with overriding the ChildrenOf in my Page Controller:

```
public function ChildrenOf($parentRef) {
    $parent = SiteTree::get_by_link($parentRef);

    if(!$parent && is_numeric($parentRef)) {
        $parent = DataObject::get_by_id('SiteTree', $parentRef);
    }

    $locale = Translatable::get_current_locale();

    if($parent && $parent->getTranslation($locale))
        return $parent->getTranslation($locale)->Children();
}
```

Comment: Seems like a decent solution. Personally, I'd probably use another method name, so that the original `ChildrenOf` still works…